# How to check for application request found in bootloader project

Tags: c, bootloader, cortex-m

Iam doing a Bootloader for an arm cortex m0 based microcontroller and for that I have gone through some projects in github and I donot understand some of the lines in the following code. What is the meaning of the line `*(__IO uint32_t*)APP_ADDRESS) & ~(RAM_SIZE-1)` in the following code. It would be great if someone explains this. Thanks in advance.

```
#define APP_ADDRESS     (uint32_t)0x08008000
#define RAM_SIZE        (uint32_t)0x00040000

uint8_t Bootloader_CheckForApplication(void)
{
    return ( ((*(__IO uint32_t*)APP_ADDRESS) & ~(RAM_SIZE-1)) == 0x20000000 ) ? BL_OK : BL_NO_APP;
}
```

Comment: It takes the 32-bit value at APP_ADDRESS (0x08008000) and rounds it down to the nearest RAM_SIZE (0x00040000). In this case it rounds the address found at 0x08008000 to the nearest 256k boundary and then checks to see if that value is 0x20000000. It is effectively checking to see if there is an application and that it is in the memory region that is in the user flash area.

Comment: Why are they checking for the value `0x20000000` only? Not any other value?

Comment: I believe User flash runs from 0x20000000 to 0x20040000 .By rounding the address down to the near 256kb (and comparing against 0x20000000) is is effectively checking that the address is any value between 0x20000000 and 0x20040000

Comment: I didnot understand the concept behind this.. we can check if the reset vector at the app address is FFFF.. then.. there is no app and if it is of some other value then app is already there right? what is happening here?

Comment: what did you see when you compiled then disassembled that code?  Work forward with basic C language knowledge and work backward from the compiler result.

Comment: But the app address is already `0x08008000` then what should one find at the location `0x20000000`? It is not app address right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to this project at https://github.com/akospasztor/stm32-bootloader

The purpose of `Bootloader_CheckForApplication()` is to determine whether a valid application is located from `APP_ADDRESS` or `0x0800 8000`. The start of this application image is actually the [vector table](https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0552/latest/the-cortex-m3-processor/exception-model/vector-table) , thus the value `*(__IO uint32_t*)APP_ADDRESS` is the initial value of the Stack Pointer (SP). (The link discusses about Cortex-M3 but the first two entries of the vector table are the same for all Cortex-M processors)

You can see the use of this initial SP and the reset vector in function `Bootloader_JumpToApplication()` in the same source file at https://github.com/akospasztor/stm32-bootloader/blob/master/Src/bootloader.c

Note that the author is using STM32L4, of which the starting address of RAM is `0x2000 0000`, the last address is `0x2003 FFFF`, and the RAM size is `0x0004 0000`. In this case, `Bootloader_CheckForApplication()` is checking if the stored initial SP is within RAM area.

However, this check will not be correct if the initial SP happens to be `0x2004 0000`, which is the highest valid value in this case. (Note that Cortex-M processors use [full descending stack](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/how-much-stack-memory-do-i-need-for-my-arm-cortex--m-applications))